# hibernate overflow relationship

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I want to query findall List
every order have List 
every OrderDetails have Order for relationship with parent Order

the problem is : 
when controller create responsebody it make overflow exception
because hibernate create order on order details
how to stop hibernate create object Orders on OrderDetails

here screenshot : 
[debuging variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzbK4.png)

OrderDetails.class

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=Orders.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "OrderID")
private Orders orders;
```

Orders.class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "orders")
private List<OrderDetails> listOrderDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@JsonBackReference` to your mapping annotation.